# How do I access a meta-property in the <head> element to determine whether or not to inject some CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I don't have access to the HTML of a website I've been asked to work on but I can insert Javascript via a custom Javascript input box on the site builder tool.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.whyottawa.ca/speakers/jeff-jeffrey/">
```

I need to set an element to "display:none" if the line above from the `<head>` element includes the content, "https://www.whyottawa.ca/speakers/*" using * as a wildcard.

I've tried something like

```
if (document.head.og:url.content === "https://www.whyottawa.ca/speakers/*") {
    document.getElementById('hide').style.display = "none";
};
```

but it doesn't like the ":" in the og:url property. Is there a way to escape this? Or a better syntax?

I also tried an attribute selector such as `meta[content|="https://www.whyottawa.ca/speakers/"]`
but I got the error, 'ReferenceError: meta is not defined'

Comment: That element is already hidden, it is a meta tag. However you can remove it with javascript. If that is what you want

Comment: And about your script, you need to use a attribute selector for it.. simple dots won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AmitPandey I will Google attribute selectors. FYI the element I want to hide is not the meta tag, it's a div in the main body of the page. Just for this example let's suppose that it has an id of "hide".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you can do this.

```
document.getElementById("hide").style.display="none";
```

Or you can use other selectors if you have some other attributes or queries.

```
document.querySelector("#hide").style.display="none";
```

Example for attribute selector
Here **name** is the attribute name **hiddenElement** is the value.

```
document.querySelector("#hide[name='hiddenElement'").style.display="none";
```

For meta tag attribute selector

```
document.querySelector("meta[property='og:url']").getAttribute('content')
```

Comment: I am answering this from mobile, so it may have some typos, let me know if something doesn't works.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about how to change the value based on the information from a `meta` element. They already have the code to set the display style.

Comment: Use the attribute selector on meta tag.. document.querySelector("meta[property='og:url']").getAttribute('content')

Comment: As @HereticMonkey said it's really the last part of your answer that is the one I need. That attribute selector works perfectly. Thanks